# Generate pages based from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, dynamically-generated

I have a JSON file with information about each person in that file (name, bio, picture, etc...).

I was wondering what technologies would allow me to generate web pages from the people in that JSON file: for example if the url is `site.com/person/steve` then it would find the name `steve` in the JSON and display info (name, bio, picture, etc...) about steve.

Preferably I would be able to able to make a persontemplate.html and whatever technology would fill in the relevant sections by grabbing the URL and finding the match in the JSON.

My current system uses JS and node.js so if I can stay within these then that's great but not essential.

I have read other stackoverflows but they don't solve my question.

Many thanks.

Comment: to render a view you can use a render template like `ejs` or etc ... [read about ejs here](https://ejs.co/)

Comment: You said you are using nodejs as backend, so you need to make a template for your pages and for each user change only the infos and send the page to the browser

Comment: @SaymoinSam okay I can make the template fine but how do I change the info depending on the URL using nodejs? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the point of using ajax with node to render views ? It is more complicated than using a templating engine ?

So you could use express (install it with npm) and handlebars (also to install with npm) to render .hbs file from your backend with `res.render('views/nameOfYourFile.hbs')`

You could also use jade which is the default template engine for express if you don't want to use handlebars.

But if you really want to get data from your backend with ajax, then just run a `script` on your page, which gets `window.location`(current url), with GET so that goes to your backend with that url and use res.send() in your backend function to send that json data. But it is much more complicated than using express… it depends what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Okay thats really helpful thanks. But how would I change the data using the URL? I can use those technologies to make a template and parse data to it, but how would I go about that using the URL, if there is no physical page at the URL the user types in?

Comment: You're welcome :) In your node.js project you have either an index.js file or an app.js file, which specifies the routes for the backend, right ? Like `app.use('/chat', chatRouter);`. Then in routes/chatRoutes you have for example `router.get('/get-id-json/:username', chatController.requireConnexion, chatController.getIdJSON);` this is from my nodejs project. The chatController.getIdJSON is a function that goes to the db to search an id corresponding to the :username parameter in the url. That url is called from an ajax call on my page that needs to be updated with that user_id.

Answer (score 1):

Having this html

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Having this script

```
// Sample data, in real app you probably load this data using an import

const data = [
  {
    name: "Ada",
    surname: "Wong",
  },
  {
    name: "Leon",
    surname: "Kennedy",
  },
];

function render() {
  const { name, surname } = getPerson();

  document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = `
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <td>${name}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Surname</td>
                  <td>${surname}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>`;
}

function getPerson() {
  const location = document.location.search.substring(1);
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location);
  const name = searchParams.get("person");

  return data.find((entry) => entry.name === name);
}

render();
```

you could try to get the data you are looking for from the url, look at the getPerson () function in the example, from there you could render the obtained data. This is a demonstration, you must consider what is related to safety and the case that you do not find results